# Add bug at the end of sprint in TFS

Tags: tfs

Our sprint backlog is usually ordered, so that we have User Stories on top and bugs at the bottom (in the order they were detected). In our backlog, all items that are in the current sprint, are on top, and the rest is ordered by topic below. Accordingly, I would like to have new bugs, added at the end of the sprint, but not at the end of the whole backlog.

As far as I know, there are two ways of adding a bug to the backlog:

Home -> Create New -> Bug
Work -> Backlog -> New -> Bug
With the first option, the bug's iteration's default value is the current sprint, and it is added at the end. However, it's not just at the end of the sprint, but and the end of the whole backlog.
With the second option, the bug is at the top of the backlog and I have to select the current iteration manually.

Both options require additional (stupid) work of the scrum-master, namely moving the items to the end of only the current sprint. Currently, I prefer the first option, as the disadvantage is "only" a messy backlog. My biggest problem with the second option is that people (including me) forget to change the iteration to the current sprint, which leads to developers not noticing a newly reported bugs.

Is there a way to have new bugs, added at the right position without any extra work?

EDIT: With the recent update, I can drag and drop multiple PBIs at the same time, which makes positioning the bugs easier. However, I would still be interested in a solution that avoids moving around bugs manually altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of TFS you are currently using, but you can:

Work -> Backlog -> Current sprint -> And in the top header you should have a NEW button.

Creating them via this route will add them to the current sprint board - and you can drag/drop their position as you wish. Or you can link them to a current PBI/User story.

Comment: That's the second option I mentioned. I was looking for a way that avoids the drag/drop operation to always position the bug at the end of the sprint, but not at the end of the backlog. However, the recent upgrade has already made my life easier, since I can drag and drop multiple PBIs at the same time now.